# One linex reger to extract two set of number from string

Tags: python, regex

The objective is extract `number` from a string.

THis can be achieved easily with `split`

```
s='/mnt/d/datat/ssome_part - Copy/s14_060319m.set.zip'

n=s.split('Copy/')[1].split('set')[0].split('_')
sbj=n[0]
sub=n[1]
```

which produce

```
sbj = {str} 's14'
sub = {str} '060319m.'
```

Please note the prefix `m` of the `sub`. This is unique for different cases.

Current suggestion allow me to capitalise the `s`, such that as `BBarmar`
sbj='S'+sbj

But, Im struggling to apply this with `regex`. ANd doing as below does not produced the intended result

```
m = re.findall(r'%s(\d+)', s)
```

Comment: There's no `%s` in your string, what is that supposed to mean in the regexp?

Comment: Just use `r'\d+'`

Comment: For the `s` just before `14`.

Comment: What about the `%`?

Comment: There's no `s` before the second number, so that will only match the first number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```py
import re
s='/mnt/d/datat/ssome_part - Copy/s14_060319m.set.zip'
match = re.search(r'(\w+)_(\w+)[^/]*$', s)
if match is not None:
    print(match.group(1).upper())
    print(match.group(2))
```

See [Python proof](https://ideone.com/us5NhS) | [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/XOIMsS/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  _                        '_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^/]*                    any character except: '/' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the regexp `\d+` to match numbers.

To match with the `s` prefix or `m` suffix, use alternatives with `|`.

```
sbj, sub = re.findall(r's\d+|\d+m', s)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Barmar. May I know ho to include the `m` in the `sub` output. Currently, it has been ommited. Instead of `060319`, I would like it to be `060319m`.

Comment: And do you also want the `s` in the `sbj` output?

Comment: You could use `r's\d+|\d+m'`

Comment: Where in the question does it say you want the letters?

Comment: I will update the question to reflect this. I have not realize about this issue previously

Comment: `+m`, this will not give correct output if it end with other letter, say., `n`,

Comment: I assumed it was always `m`. Please update the question with the exact criteria for each number and letter that should be matched.

Comment: Your update is not helpful. It says "prefix m", but it's a suffix, not a prefix. And what letters are allowed there? What letters are allowed before `sbj`? I don't understand the part about capitalising at all.

Comment: Anyway, it should be pretty obvious how to modify this to allow different letters. You can use `[a-z]` to allow any letter. If you want to allow uppercase as well, use `flags=re.I` to make it case-insensitive.

Comment: This is all really basic regexp. If you can't do it yourself, you need to read a tutorial to learn it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only `num_num` try this:

```
s='/mnt/d/datat/ssome_part - Copy/s14_060319m.set.zip'
re.findall(r'\d+_\d+', s)[0].split('_')
# ['14', '060319']
```

Or if you maybe have multi number better is get list of nums like below:

```
s='/mnt/d/datat/ssome20_part10 - Copy/s14_060319m.set.zip'
lst_num = re.findall(r'\d+', s)
lst_num
# ['20', '10', '14', '060319']
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just simply:

```
>>> sbj, sub = re.findall('[0-9]+', s)
>>> sbj
'14'
>>> sub
'060319'
>>>
```